# Launching Springsource tool giving some error

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Fow the last few days I used to work on STS. But today it is not launching and giving following window. So, I reinstalled STS. But the problem still exits. Can some one help in sorting it out?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after few hours. Some guy had same problem and solved 
[here](http://techboard.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/error-starting-eclipse/#comment-269):

> Eclipse is trying to get the version of java that is installed on system. you might have installed that latest one but there are possibilities that any upgradation of later softwares has replaced the java.exe files in system32 folder with older version. All you need to do is to run eclipse with clean parameters. Create a batch file in the directory where eclipse.exe is and write this line in it `eclipse -clean -vmargs -Xmx256m`

Comment: I'm surprised this question isn't more popular. I'm glad I found it though; I'm sure I would have spent a long time trying to figure it out.